# Замена введённых символов в input

Tags: python

Интересует такой вопрос: пользователь вводит какое-то значение в input() и ему выводит его же символы. Допустим, он написал 'abcd', на экран сразу вывелось это значение. Можно ли сделать так, чтоб это 'absd' показывалось в консоле как '****'

Comment: Там не особо с вариантами: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9202224/getting-a-hidden-password-input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Установите библиотеку:

```
pip install Inline-input
```

Простой пример:

```
import inline #Импортируем библиотеку
input = inline.input #Заменяем стандартный input

s = input(secret=True) #Введёный текст будет заменён звездочками
print(f"Вы написали: {s}") #Но вы всё так же можете узнать что пользователь ввёл
```

Comment: есть какая-то библиотека подобная на MacOS?

Answer (score 1):

Да, можно. Самый простой способ - просто возьми длину строки и напечатай столько звездочек, сколько есть символов с строке

```
a = input()
print('*' * len(a))
```